# Set ContentType of new window opened in JavaScript following MVC post

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-3, contenttype

I need to open a new window and set the contents to whatever was determined by a post to my MVC controller when a link is clicked. Here's how I'm currently doing it.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/controller/mycontroller',
        data: { mydata: data },
        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        },
        success: function (response) {
            win_detail = window.open('', 'name');
            win_detail.document.write(response);
        }
    });
```

The controller currently is processing what html should be on the page and putting it in the ViewBag. It's also putting what the Response.ContentType should be in the ViewBag. My mycontroller.cshtml I have something like this.

```
@{
Response.ContentType = ViewBag.ContentType;
}

<head></head>
<body>
@ViewBag.MyHtml
</body>
```

This doesn't actually set the ContentType. Does anyone know how I can? I can change my entire structure to whatever accomplishes this.

Comment: Can you not just use a get request and open the new window with the given url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absent some other reason, I'd attempt to use a GET request and just open the window to the given URL.

```
win_detail = window.open('/controller/action?mydata=' + data, 'name');
```

Depending on your data you may need to serialize it differently.

```
var form_data = $('form').serialize();
win_detail = window.open( '/controller/action?' + form_data, 'name');
```

Comment: Thank you, I thought my data was going to be too large for a GET, but I tried that and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the ContentType to the view via ViewBag, try setting it in the controller before you return.

Comment: Would I do that with Response.ContentType = newContentType;? That doesn't seem to be working either. I'd figured issue has to do with fact that I'm just sticking the returned response into an already created window instead of creating it with the correct content type. Just don't know how to change that.